# Syntax highlighting for LaTeX code in RStudio

Tags: r, latex, rstudio

I have recently started writing mathematical documents using Bookdown and RStudio, and I am looking for a way to setup syntax highlighting for LaTeX code. I know that I can customise the syntax highlighting using editor themes, and I have found [this tool](https://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Monokai) for creating them, but I don't know what to enter into the "scope" fields to achieve the highlighting I want.

I would like something similar to the syntax highlighting in TeXworks (which is what I'm used to). This has separate highlight colours for special characters, commands beginning and ending LaTeX environments, LaTeX packages, and control sequences. Ideally, I'd also like another highlight colour for text in mathmode, and I would like the highlighting to be the same for text that is inside or outside [Bookdown's equivalent of Theorem environments](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#theorems).

Based on trying a few themes and looking at them in the editor, I think that keyword highlighting will highlight LaTeX control sequences and support.function will highlight text in mathmode, but these only work outside of Bookdown's environments.

Is it possible to achieve the highlighting I want? And if so, how?