# Highlight LateX Code Math Environment within R Studio using Sweave and .RNW File

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, sweave

When creating a pdf involving LateX and R code in Rstudio, is it possible to have LaTeX code highlighted whenever a math environment is created?

I am frequently having errors from unmatched $ symbols and the debugger doesn't make them easy to find. I would like the appearance of the code  within a .RNW file in R studio to emphasize whether or not I have closed math mode when writing LateX code.

This question from over three years ago is similar

[Syntax highlighting for LaTeX code in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61823757/syntax-highlighting-for-latex-code-in-rstudio)

and remains unanswered. However that question references a tool through a link that no longer works, and is regarding Bookdown, which I am not interested in currently.

Comment: I don't use .Rnw files much nowadays, but when I did, I generally used TeXworks as the editor instead of RStudio.  It supports syntax highlighting.  Instructions for using TeXworks to edit .Rnw files are included in the `patchDVI` R package.

Comment: Did you find something preferred to .rnw files?

Comment: Yes, generally I find R Markdown preferable.  I can insert LaTeX math when necessary.  It is harder to customize, though I think it is just as flexible as .Rnw if you are willing to work at it.  Myself, I'm happy with the defaults, and with those, it is much easier to use than typing LaTeX all the time as you do with .Rnw.